# Strings not updating

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm sorry if this question is not very clear,if so, please tell me what I need to update/elaborate, thank you!

My strings do not seem to update itself when I am updating another string. I am sorry, but this is very hard to explain in text, especially for me, my english isn't that great so I'm sorry for that. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
public class Paths
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The current selected server.
    /// </summary>
    public static string SelectedServer { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the current selected server.
    /// </summary>
    public static string SelectedServerLocation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The path of the application itself.
    /// </summary>
    public static string Root { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The path of the Microcraft folder.
    /// </summary>
    public static string MicrocraftFolder { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The path of the Server Files folder.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ServersFolder { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the minecraft.jar file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string MinecraftJar { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the bukkit.jar file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string BukkitJar { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the bukkit.yml file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string BukkitYml { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the server.properties file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ServerProperties { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the root xml file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string XmlRoot { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the server xml file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string XmlServer { get; set; }

    public Paths()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedServer))
        {
            Xml.Setting.path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\microcraft\\settings.xml";
            SelectedServer = Xml.Setting.GetSetting("Servers/Current", "T4G Demo");
        }

        Root = string.Format("{0}\\", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        MicrocraftFolder = string.Format("{0}microcraft\\", Root);
        ServersFolder = string.Format("{0}servers\\", MicrocraftFolder);
        SelectedServerLocation = string.Format("{0}{1}", ServersFolder, SelectedServer);
        MinecraftJar = string.Format("{0}{1}\\minecraft.jar", ServersFolder, SelectedServer);
        BukkitJar = string.Format("{0}{1}\\bukkit.jar", ServersFolder, SelectedServer);
        BukkitYml = string.Format("{0}{1}\\bukkit.yml", ServersFolder, SelectedServer);
        ServerProperties = string.Format("{0}{1}\\server.properties", ServersFolder, SelectedServer);
        XmlRoot = string.Format("{0}settings.xml", MicrocraftFolder);
        XmlServer = string.Format("{0}{1}\\settings.xml", MicrocraftFolder, SelectedServer);
    }
}
```

This is how I edit/call the strings:

```
Servers.Paths.SelectedServer = SelectedServer;
Xml.Setting.path = Servers.Paths.XmlServer;
```

But the `Servers.Paths.XmlServer` is not updates with the new `SelectedServer` :(.

Comment: Either your properties shouldn't be static, or the class shouldn't have a constructor at all.  It's not clear from the code which is the case.  My guess is that's at the root of your problem somewhere.

Comment: @csharpler Yes, but doesn't it refreshes the string automatically?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but that's not even the entirety of your problems.

Comment: As I said before, the first thing you need to address is that your properties are all static but you have a constructor, and in that constructor you seem to be treating the properties as instance properties.  It should be one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't actually have any code for updating anything once `SelectedServer` has been modified.

You set `SelectedServer` inside the constructor, the constructor is called before anything else to actually build your object.

If you want to update other things once `SelectedServer` changes, you need to do something akin to:

```
private static string _selectedServer;
public static string SelectedServer
{
   get { return _selectedServer; }
   set
   {
      _selectedServer = value;
      // Update other fields here.
   }
}
```

Further, I'd recommend something like:

```
public class Paths
{
    private static string _selectedServer;
    /// <summary>
    /// The current selected server.
    /// </summary>
    public static string SelectedServer
    {
        get { return _selectedServer; }
        set
        {
            _selectedServer = value;
            _updateFields();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the current selected server.
    /// </summary>
    public static string SelectedServerLocation { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The path of the application itself.
    /// </summary>
    public static string Root { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The path of the Microcraft folder.
    /// </summary>
    public static string MicrocraftFolder { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The path of the Server Files folder.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ServersFolder { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the minecraft.jar file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string MinecraftJar { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the bukkit.jar file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string BukkitJar { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the bukkit.yml file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string BukkitYml { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the server.properties file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ServerProperties { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the root xml file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string XmlRoot { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the server xml file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string XmlServer { get; set; }

    public Paths(string selectedServer)
    {
        // Set any default values here
        SelectedServer = selectedServer;
    }

    private static void _updateFields()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedServer))
        {
            Xml.Setting.path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\microcraft\\settings.xml";
            SelectedServer = Xml.Setting.GetSetting("Servers/Current", "T4G Demo");
        }

        Root = string.Format("{0}\\", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        MicrocraftFolder = string.Format("{0}microcraft\\", Root);
        ServersFolder = string.Format("{0}servers\\", MicrocraftFolder);
        SelectedServerLocation = string.Format("{0}{1}", ServersFolder, SelectedServer);
        MinecraftJar = string.Format("{0}{1}\\minecraft.jar", ServersFolder, SelectedServer);
        BukkitJar = string.Format("{0}{1}\\bukkit.jar", ServersFolder, SelectedServer);
        BukkitYml = string.Format("{0}{1}\\bukkit.yml", ServersFolder, SelectedServer);
        ServerProperties = string.Format("{0}{1}\\server.properties", ServersFolder, SelectedServer);
        XmlRoot = string.Format("{0}settings.xml", MicrocraftFolder);
        XmlServer = string.Format("{0}{1}\\settings.xml", MicrocraftFolder, SelectedServer);
    }
}
```

I've had the constructor require the selected server so that you can have it set as everything else seems to hinge upon that value.

I would recommend revising the structure of the class though, removing the statics and the such and just really thinking about what you need from it.

Comment: Okai, so I need to put my `Servers.Paths.XmlServer` string in there, under set?

Comment: Anything that needs to change if `SelectedServer` changes needs updating here, my guess is that you need to move the code in your constructor into a private `Update` method that you call when `SelectedServer` is set.

Comment: Huh, could you give me a little example :(? I'm not really that good at doing this.

Comment: I see, but does this happen automatically if I update the `SelectedServer` string? Thanks btw ^_^

Comment: Clint what do you think the `Auto Property` is used for I think that the reason it's not updating is because of something else. I tested his `public static string SelectedServer { get; set; }` and did some code setting the value(s) and they update so what he has `public static string SelectedServer { get; set; }` defined is the same as doing the long hand version of doing a `Getter and Setter` the way that you have depicted

Comment: @DJKRAZE his issue is that he wants things to update when `SelectedServer` changes, with an auto property that's not going to happen.

Comment: the problem seems to be `Paths(string selectedServer)` Method is not being called anywhere in his existing code so therefore `SelectedServer` can not be updated..

Comment: `Clint` I understand but he's not even setting and or changing the value to begin with.. I would suggest that the `OP` use the `Debugger` and step thru the code and I am sure he will see immediately what I am talking about

Comment: @DJKRAZE The string gets updated, but the other string (XmlServer) doesn't update itself with the new servername.

Comment: @DJKRAZE you're trying to get too large a picture, he's clearly just gotten confused as to the order of execution of a constructor and can't understand why he's written code to set properties based on another isn't working, he just needs to lift it out into an update method and call that from the property that is to trigger an update.

Comment: I was just pointing out the obvious of what I have initially seen when taking a quick glance.. either way I am not questioning your answer I was more or less questioning his approach.. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

When you say `a = b` in C# you aren't saying, "From now on, `a` and `b` both `point` to the same thing and changing one changes the other."  What you are saying is, "take the value that is in `b` *right this second* and set the value of `a` to be that value.  After you've executed this line of code changing what `b` is will have no effect on `a`, and changing `a` will have no effect on what's in `b`.

That is why changing one of your properties is not affecting the other given the code that you have.

That said, since you haven't really described what you're *actually* trying to do, it's hard to say how you should properly solve what your true problem is.

Comment: Ooh I see, is there any way I can make that work? What I'm trying to do is let the other strings get the value from `SelectedServer` and then add it to their string. (So it changes dynamically).

Comment: @FoxyShadoww There are ways of having that behavior, but I doubt that it's what you want in your case.  As you haven't given any information as to the underlying problem you're trying to solve, as I said in my answer, there is insufficient information to explain how to properly address this issue.

Comment: I am sure that that is what I want :), I just don't know how to explain my problem in proper English :(.